# angular ng-repeat if property is defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to ng-repeat through an array, but need to hide if a property is undefined.

I tried doing to do is this:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people | filter:search" ng-if="last == undefined">
    {{person.last}}, {{person.first}}
</div>
```

Heres a basic jsfiddle of what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4556/

Thank you!

Comment: One possible approach is using [two filters](http://jsfiddle.net/TQQ7u/) instead. But that, of course, will exclude the corresponding rows from DOM rather than hide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="person in people | filter:search" ng-show="person.last">
    {{person.last}}, {{person.first}}
</div>
```

Try testing for person.last instead of just 'last'.
I used ng-show instead of ng-if as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just hide the rows, then mccainz's answer will work.  If you want to actually remove them from the DOM, then create a filter:

```
$scope.fullNameFilter = function(person){
    return person.last;
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people | filter: fullNameFilter">
```

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZdgJ/)